# Initializing a JavaScript array in Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses Razor in the views. I'm building a JavaScript array in my controller. Sometimes though, it will not exist. For that reason, I want to initialize it on the client-side. In an attempt to do that, I have the following:

```
var list = '@(ViewBag.List == null ? [] : ViewBag.List)';
```

Unfortunately, that generates an error. The error is:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '['
```

Is there a way for me to use the ternary operator with arrays in razor? If so, how?

Comment: `[]` isn't valid C# code. What type is ViewBag.List? Do you want to serialize something into JavaScript?

Comment: Try `var list = '@(ViewBag.List == null ? "[]" : ViewBag.List)';`

Comment: @elolos That approach generates `var list = '[]';` not `var list = [];`

Comment: Sorry, meant `var list = @(ViewBag.List == null ? "[]" : ViewBag.List);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Javascript operates using JSON, you should JSON serialize your list:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json

var list = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.List));
list = list || [];
```

In general, `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))` is the proper way to inject a C# object `obj` into a view as JSON. `IHtmlString Html.Raw(string)` simply returns the `string` it is passed and renders it without any HTML escaping, which is what you want when you are rendering an object as JSON into a block of Javascript code.

Comment: I thought I've read _pickles_ somewhere here. Now it disappeared.

Comment: I think when you posted the first _version_ of the answer there was a `Model` with _pickles_ in its name. Nevermind. :)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Ahaha yes I copied a snippet out of a view of my own and forgot to switch out for `ViewBag.List` but then immediately corrected it. It wasn't "pickles" though.

Comment: I might be hungry. That's why. Haha